# How to return matches array and also result string using preg_replace?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to accomplish two things, and I was wondering if both can be accomplished with preg_replace.

I need to alter a string. Right now I am using preg_replace:

```
preg_replace($terms,$replace_with,$string,1);
```

where $terms is an array of terms, and $replace_with is also an array.

But I also need to return the matches in a separate array (to update other values later), because there are several terms, I don't know which one has matched.

The only way I know how to accomplish this, is to run preg_match first, which by default returns the matches array, and then preg_replace to actually replace the string with the new values.

**Is there a way to return the string, and the matches with preg_replace only?**

My end goal, is to have the altered $string (which is currently accomplished with preg_replace), but also an array with the $terms matched.

Comment: i did, but I don't see how that helps. I don't want to group matches and replace the string with them. I need something similar to the $matches array return from preg_match, so that I can use it outside preg_replace. can you provide me with an example?

Comment: Is `$replace_with` an array or a string?

Comment: Maybe `preg_match_all()` and then `str_replace()` with the matches.

Comment: $replace_with is also an array.

Answer (score 0):

No, but if `$terms` and `$replace_with` have numeric keys *(without gaps)* you can use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$matches = [];
foreach($terms as $k=>$term) {
    $rep = $replace_with[$k];
    $string = preg_replace_callback($term, function ($m) use ($rep, &$matches) {
        $matches[] = $m[0];
        return $rep;
    }, $string, 1);
}
```

Note that using `foreach` + `preg_replace[_callback]` does exactly the same thing than using `preg_replace` with an array as first parameter or using `preg_replace_callback_array`. (ie: the string is parsed once by item.)

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try. I had look into preg_replace_callback before but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some preg_replace option.